# One model containing two relationships of the same type?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I'd like to solve this:

I got one model (`Position`). A position should contain a `PositionProduct`, which holds the ordered product with possible customizations and the `OriginalPositionProduct`, which basically contains the **original** product without any possible customizations. I need both to compare the actually ordered `PositionProduct` with it's original later.

Actually, this would not work:

```
public function product()
{
    return $this->hasOne(PositionProduct::class);
}

public function originalproduct()
{
    return $this->hasOne(PositionProduct::class);
}
```

as the `PositionProduct` only contains the id of the position:

```
$table->bigInteger('position_id')->nullable();
```

As `position_id` is the same, `product()` and `originalproduct()` would return the same result.

So my question is:

How can I relate two instances of the same type but with different values to a model?

Comment: Do you want to seperate it with some conditions on query ? like to query the same model but with different conditions ?

Comment: You can pass a second parameter to `hasOne` to specify the relationship's foreign key. `hasOne(PositionProduct::class, 'position_id');` `hasOne(PositionProduct::class, 'original_position_id');`. This way, you get two different results. You'll need to add a second column to `PositionProduct`'s table though.